# File explorer, Google Chrome and Google Drive autopin on startup. How to remove autopinning?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, taskbar, pin

I have a little problem with my computer. Everytime I start it, it autopins these three applications to the taskbar. I don't mind Chrome and File Explorer but I don't want to have Google Drive there. I have already tried making a bat file that removes the file from "C:\Users\W\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar". It removed it from the folder, but it stayed in the taskbar.

Thereafter I tried killing the explorer.exe task and then restarting it. Didn't work. Still there, and when I clicked it, it just told me the shortcut file doesn't exist anymore, but still icon. After that I tried removing the iconcache.db file from the local folder and restarted explorer.exe. That removed the icon, but the empty file remained without a proper icon. Then I tried removing TaskBand folder and restarting explorer.exe, but the file was still there, and the icon came back.

Answer (score 0):

To clear all pinned apps on the taskbar, use this `.bat` file:

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A "%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*"
REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband /F
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```